# Can I customize preprocesses in R caret's package?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using the `caret` package for training regressions.  Since I came across of it, I knew I was gonna need it.

I have looked at the section for preprocessing the data set.  While some of it I can apply directly, there was another section that I want to try which I didn't find how to.  Let me explain in detail.

Say I have three types of variables.

```
bell_shaped <- randr(m*h, mu, sig)
non_bell    <-  expr(m*j, lambda)
factor      <- sample(c('a','b','c'), m*k, replace=F) 
data        <- as.data.frame(matrix(
    cbind(bell_shaped, non_bell, factor)), nrow=m))
```

Each of the three types I process differently.  For bell shaped, I scale them which I saw how; the non-bell I want to get the quantiles, and for the factor just the levels.

And the quantiles depend on the training set, therefore need preprocessing.  While I did find a section for it in the [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html) package, I didn't find how to.

Is this a functionality of the package, is there another tool with which I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. There are [custom methods](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html) to do this.

[This example](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html#Illustration4) is a demonstration.

Comment: Great! This certainly did it.  What an awesome package.